# Creating a Linux executable file from a bunch of files/directories

Tags: executable

I have a directory, with a small scructure:

```
script.sh
dist/
dist/program.jar
log/
log/error.log
conf/
conf/program.conf
```

The `script.sh` do some checks, and start `program.jar` with a lot of parameters.

There's a way to encapsulate all this structure in a single file (like the `directory.app` executables in OSX), and made this file a executable?

Comment: You mean an installer? Or something that contains everything in binary form and can be run directly? Both are possible but the second can't be answered here. It will involve you turning it into a program in your favorite language and including the data in the resulting binary.

Comment: Thanks @terdon. What I want is the second option: a container to run directly (like the `directory.app` structure in OSX). Maybe I need to rewrite the app to accomplish the `script.sh` objective. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can not run a single executable and have your program work without being unpacked. The reason is that your program would expect to be able to access its files using standard syscalls, and if you have those files packed inside an archive, they will not be visible to Linux.

What you can do is use [makeself](http://www.megastep.org/makeself/) to make a single self-extractable executable archive. Then your user would run the executable, it would extract the files from the archive, and then the user can run the installed program.

Another alternative, since you are using Java, is to pack files inside the .jar archive, and restructure your code. Then you could distribute the single .jar file and the user run it with `java -jar`.